# How filter Same lat,log value in one list?

Tags: java, android

I have web-service which give list of property at a particular area
       My problem is that all property have to show on map if any case there
       are more than two properties lat and long same in list then that property will shown on same bubbles on google map I have been parse the result but I unable to filter those properties which have same lat and long in xml.I am trying as  after parsinng an arraylist return :-

```
 private Vector groupTheList(ArrayList<Applicationdataset> arrayList) 
{
    Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>> mgroupvector = new Vector<ArrayList<Applicationdataset>>();
    ArrayList<Applicationdataset> mfirstList = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>();
    ArrayList<Applicationdataset> mylist=null;
    int sizeoflist = arrayList.size();
    for(int index =0;index<arrayList.size();index++)
    {
         //ArrayList<Applicationdataset> mylist= mgroupvector.get(index);
         if(mylist==null)
         {
             mylist = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>(); 
         }
         mfirstList.add(arrayList.get(index));

        for(int mindex=1;mindex<arrayList.size();mindex++)
        {
         if(arrayList.get(index).getLatitude().equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(mindex).getLatitude()) &&
                 arrayList.get(index).getLongitude().equalsIgnoreCase(arrayList.get(mindex).getLongitude()))
         {
             mfirstList.add(arrayList.get(mindex));
             arrayList.remove(mindex);
         }
        }
        mylist.addAll(mfirstList);
        mgroupvector.add(mylist);
        mfirstList.clear();
        arrayList.remove(index);
        index-=1;
    }
    mgroupvector.add(arrayList);
    return mgroupvector;

}
```

but further I have unable to do any one please help me. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
.......
private Collection<List<Applicationdataset>> groupTheList(ArrayList<Applicationdataset> arrayList) {
    Map<Key, List<Applicationdataset>> map = new HashMap<Key, List<Applicationdataset>>();
    for(Applicationdataset appSet: arrayList){
        Key<String, String> key = new Key(appSet.getLatitude(), appSet.getLongtitude());
        List<Applicationdataset> list = map.get(key);
        if(list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<Applicationdataset>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(appset);
    }
    return map.values();
}
........

class Key {
    String _lat;
    String _lon;

    Key(String lat, String lon) {
        _lat = lat;
        _lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Key key = (Key) o;

        if (!_lat.equals(key._lat)) return false;
        if (!_lon.equals(key._lon)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = _lat.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + _lon.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx lot for reply but I have need those properties which have same lat,long store in same list or in map on same key...please suggest me

Comment: Some changes - for each key in the map - list of objects with same lat and lon.

Comment: I want to One thing when I got Map View throug this method how I'll can Iterate this map?

Comment: Its not working ,1 how I will get those values which have not unique lat ,long?